# Asp.net MVC Web API Call Redirect to Accountcontroller Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

My code is

**RouteConfig:**

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**WebAPIConfig:**

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    }
```

**WebAPI Controller:**

```
public class ServicesController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

**AccountCtonroller:**

```
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        // User Login functionality
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

        return View();
    }
```

Global.asax.cs

```
   protected void Application_Start()
    {                     
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);            
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Issue I am facing here is:
1. when i invoke Webapi http://localhost/myapplication/api/services in browser, it redirect to

http://localhost/myapplication/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%myapplication%2Fapi%2Fservices

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks,

Comment: FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters); - These have the authentication filter included I suspect. Try to put that one in comment.

Comment: how are you invoking your service? By simply putting URL " http://localhost/myapplication/api/services" in browser?

Comment: yes. by simple putting url and it invoke get function in servicescontroller but return login page instead of json result "hello world"

Comment: @KyorCode i tried with comment filterconfig as you mentioned but nothing worked for me.

Comment: did you choose an authentication mode while creating the project?

Comment: Yes. there is authentication implemented in Account controller
        private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            }
        }

Comment: try adding [AllowAnonymous] attribute to your controller class and if that avoids the authentication redirection

Comment: [AllowAnonymous] works fine, but in this case, [authorize] attribute do not work as i need to implement basic authentication

Comment: @Qamar i added [AllowAnonymous] and its started to work fine, but [Authorize] attribute is not working properly. It is executing basic authentication classes but bypassing authentication

Comment: is this authentication is your own implementation?

Comment: yes. I am implementing this one for web api http://timney.net/basic-authentication-with-web-api/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80747/discussion-between-qamar-and-aqdas).

Comment: Do you see any value in Request.User inside your method execution?

Answer (score -1):

i think your problem is that you dont set action on webapiconfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param}",
            defaults: new { param = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and you need call to controller with action something like:
    http://localhost/myapplication/api/services/Get

And add [AllowAnonymous] as @qamar sais

Comment: In this case, [authorize] attribute on web api controller class will not work whereas i need to implement basic authentication for web api once this issue is fixed